# Media query is not called

Tags: html, css

Can anyone see why this media query does not work? The first part of the CSS .header-x1 is working fine. But I would like to change font size when the max width is 768px. But nothing happens when I run my code here. Can anybody see why?

```
<p class="header-xl">
   This is a test
</p

.header-xl {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 160px;
    }

@media(max-width:768px) {
    header-xl  {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a . for the class in media query, Instead of header-xl add .header-xl

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .header-xl  {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you need `.header-xl` not `header-xl` inside the media query

Answer (score 0):

Change `header-xl` to **.header-xl**

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .header-xl  {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}
```